Masking authorisation header in Karate log and report
I have read through log masking section in the karate document => https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#log-masking
However, I still could not find any example that allows me to mask the authorization header in the API request.
(I tried to modify the DemoLogModifier class but I don't think I get it right)

Would be great if someone can show me the working code.
Thank you.

There is already an example here: DemoLogModifier.java and here: headers-masking.feature
I suggest you can implement enableForUri() as follows to start with:
@Override
public boolean enableForUri(String uri) {
    return true;
}

Maybe that's all you need, because you probably want to mask all URLs.

What does this method "enableForUri()" do? I noticed that by changing the method body from "return uri.contains("/headers");"  to "return true;" make the log masking works!

@TonyThongsinthop so it can be used if you want to focus on only some API "paths". you can also talk to a friend who knows Java to understand this better
